# Dependency Injection Constructor doesn't sees object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, maui

In fresh MAUI.NET I have registered the singletons in MauiProgram.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<InformationView>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<InformationViewModel>();
```

I have public empty class InformationViewModel and I have default ContentView (XAML) item with the .cs part content like this:

```
    public InformationViewModel viewModel;
    public InformationView(InformationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = viewModel;
    }
```

in MainPage.cs I try to get my registered singletons like that:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InformationView view = new InformationView(InformationViewModel informationViewModel);
    }
```

I have look for a `MonkeyFinder` sample application provided by Microsoft and its training by Gerald Versluis. It seems that `MonkeyService` is done in same way and is working while I get this errors in the above line of MainPage.cs:

> Error CS1729  'InformationView' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments
> Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected
> Error   CS0119  'InformationViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
> Error   CS0103  The name 'informationViewModel' does not exist in the current context

What should I do to fix it?

**Edit**

Following seems to be working and "singleton" properties are handled - I got always the same instance whenever I call it.

```
InformationViewModel informationViewModel = new InformationViewModel();
InformationView view = new InformationView(informationViewModel);
```

**Edit 2**
It wasn't obvious for me, that you need to trigger "the first object in hierarchy of construction" by DI and this would happen. I was expecting that if I create a "new instance" it would not "fire" the whole DI for internal dependencies. So `MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services.GetService<InformationView>();` would do all DI I was expecting.

Comment: `new InformationView(InformationViewModel informationViewModel);` is not valid c#

Comment: when writing

`InformationViewModel informationViewModel = new InformationViewModel();
InformationView view = new InformationView(informationViewModel);`

you are not using the DI infrastructure, just allocating new objects.

Comment: Thanks @Sté . So my question is about to getting to know how to use DI infrastructure. For example following (without new) is not working either: InformationView view = InformationView(InformationViewModel vm);
And the way I get singleton usually is by ServiceProvider which for Windows is MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services.GetService<MyRegisteredClass>() ( I have seperated utility class to handle this).

Comment: So..., you have answered your own question :)

To use the DI infrastructure, you have to write 

`MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services.GetService<InformationView>()`

Comment: IMHO, _View_ and _Model_ are *not* meant to be singleton.

Comment: @Sté not really :) because I can take a service from DI in code but now I am looking for the usage of DI in constructor. The example of what I am talking is MonkeyService in this repository https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/dotnet-maui-workshop/blob/main/Finish/MonkeyFinder/ViewModel/MonkeysViewModel.cs

Comment: Sorry, i can't see what you trying to achieve. _Views_ are managed by the MAUI framework, which uses DI internally. You don't have to instanciate your view manually (by using `new`), it will defeat the very purpose of DI framework. Your responsability is to write the routing (like [this](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/dotnet-maui-workshop/blob/3782ce4130887e39eb58b235efa61acdcd1c0e01/Part%204%20-%20Platform%20Features/MonkeyFinder/AppShell.xaml.cs#L9)?).

Comment: Thanks for discussion. I am afraid I do something other way. But from the experience from WPF I am used to create views. I had application that are deciding what view to create at runtime.
Anyway in "edit 2" section I have explained what was my missing point. now I do just 
        MainPage = ServiceProvider.GetService<MainPage>(); in App.xaml.cs and everything (MainPage have some sub views) is done by DI :) Actually you speak about routing which is possible if you go with shell. But I do not want to use shell. I have build my own navigation which is performing for my case well. Thanks!

Comment: And now what else do you need ？

Comment: @JianweiSun thank you, nothing more in this issue :) in edit2 there is my explenation